# RSpec system specs not working with Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, selenium-chromedriver

I'm in the process of moving from RSpec 3.6 feature specs to RSpec 3.7 system specs.

With the following setup, all the specs work fine

```
#gems.rb
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.7.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '3.6.0'
  gem 'geckodriver-helper', '0.0.4'
end

#rails_helper.rb
config.before(:each, type: :system) do
  driven_by :rack_test
end

config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do
  driven_by :selenium, using: :firefox
end
```

However, if I try to switch to Chrome

```
#gems.rb
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.7.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '3.6.0'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper', '1.1.0'
end

#rails_helper.rb 
config.before(:each, type: :system) do
  driven_by :rack_test
end

config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome
  # OR
  driven_by :selenium_chrome
  #OR
  driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
end
```

The specs don't work. Chrome fires up but for some reason I haven't understood yet, it is not able to log into the app.

Any ideas what this may happen?

Thanks.

Comment: More details are needed here. Show the content of your specs. When you say "it is not able to log in the app", what does that really mean? Authentication fails even with the right credentials?

Comment: Yes. It fails. Thanks